# how to write a code if i want to display thankyou view from localhost and my computer and not from interet destination?

Tags: php, paypal

im really new to PHP, and have some questions...

I have been implemeting a PayPal payment form, the code goes like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US"> <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="<?php echo $shipping; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.predragstevanovic.com/webprodavnica/index.php?view=thankyou"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="predragstevanovic.com/webprodavnica/">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="predragstevanovic.com/webprodavnica/paypal.php"/>
<input type="submit" name="pay now" value="Plati" />
```

My root directory is `webprodavnica` and inside this directory i have: `index.php`, `db_fns.php`, `cart_fns.php`, `paypal.php` and then I have another directory named `views` with 2 more directories inside: `layouts` with `shop.php` and `shop` with `plati_kupovinu.php`, `index.php` and `thankyou.php`.

Im stucked when I press pay button, it goes to paypal, and when finish transaction does nothing, and i want to redirect me to my thankyou.php page on my server. I'm hosting this locally because I could not find a free hosting to test this application... if anybody can suggest one that would be cool. I don't have a domain either, `predragstevanovic.com` is just an example.

So, what's happening is that the user clicks on the pay button and that takes the user to to paypal (they leave my page) and there they finish the transaction but does not return to my page, where you want to show `thankyou.php`.

**How to write the code if i want to display thankyou view from my server?**

Thanks

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. If you want to do it locally, you'll need something like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) so you can set up a local server for PHP to work on

Comment: i have xampp as well, just need to put something instead of "http://www.predragstevanovic.com/webprodavnica/index.php?view=thankyou"

Comment: Could you show your HTML? IT seems to be you describe <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.predragstevanovic.com/webprodavnica/index.php?view=thankyou" />

And then you want to read that value on the server side, is that so?  If not, what is the expected result. Please add that to the question.

Comment: If you want you avoid doing the `?view=thankyou` you should pass a `$_POST variable`

Comment: and i want everything to be on my computer not on internet
i already have xampp

Comment: Please add the code to your question, and remove this comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $view = "Thank You"?>
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $view;?>">
```

You can set the value of $view as you want. 
If you want to set the value dynamically (may be from ajax call) then you can use javascript to do it

Make a json call from your js to that thankyou.php. And from thankyou.php , return a json_encode of what you want to send.  In the js you can set the value using the 'id' attribute of your input field.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

**Your questions changes over time. Ignore the previous part.**
**Edit:** From my experience when you integrate your site with a paypal or any payment site, you need to provide a  URL as a parameter. If you are providing at and stil it is not being redirected to your site, i doubt there is a configuration problem, or there is some error.

Comment: i forgot to mention that i created view folder and thankyou.php created on mycomputer in root destination

Answer (score 0):

The problem boils down to building a valid URL to set in the `input return` that PayPal is going to read to know where to redirect the user. Since you don't have a domain you will have to use your IP to identify your server.

Under the assumption that you have a public IP you can query it by [asking Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=here).

---

Now, since you are interested in finding a hosting for your application you will want a solution that will be easy to adapt. What I suggest is a configuration file. Let's call it `configuration.php`.

We must place this configuration file in the server, but we don't want the user to be able to access it directly, to address that we use the following code:

```
<?php
    if (count(get_included_files()) == 1)
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

This code check if the file is been accessed directly by the client (that is: the user acceses to the url for this file as opposed of being included in another PHP file or readed in the server). If that happen it will return a 404 as if the file weren't there.

---

You can use this file to set some variable that you can access in other PHP files, to do so you must include this file, like so:

```
<?php require_once('configuration.php'); ?>
```

Please note that the code I presented above will allow to include the file without problems.

---

Now, you will set in that file a variable with your public IP. This is the recommended way to do it:

```
<?php
    if (count(get_included_files()) == 1)
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        exit();
    }
    $_configuration = array
    (
        'Server' => '127.0.0.1' //place your real public IP
    );
?>
```

Note: `$_configuration` is an associative array, you can set to it many values, for example:

```
$_configuration = array
(
    'Server' => '127.0.0.1',
    'MySQL_User' => 'MrAdmin',
    'MySQL_Password' => 'ACRYSPXN'
);
```

---

To access this variables you would do the following:

```
<?php
    require_once('configuration.php');
    echo $_configuration['Server'];
?>
```

Note: `require_once` will include each file only once, so you can place `require_once('configuration.php');` many times in your file without problems.

---

Finally, we will use that configuration variable to crate the Url you pass to paypal:

```
<?php
    require_once('configuration.php');
    $server = $_configuration['Server'];
?>
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://<?php echo $server; ?>/webprodavnica/index.php?view=thankyou"/>
```

Here your IP is taking the place of the domain. This allows you to set your domiang (once you get one) in the configuration file and it should work correctly:

```
<?php
    if (count(get_included_files()) == 1)
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        exit();
    }
    $_configuration = array
    (
        'Server' => 'predragstevanovic.com' //place your real Internet domain
    );
?>
```

The final detail would be redirect the user correctly to `thankyou.php`. You could implement that as follows:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
    {
        //The server recieved a GET request ...
        if (array_key_exists('view', $_GET))
        {
            //... with the view parameter ...
            if ($_GET['view'] == 'thankyou')
            {
                //... having the value 'thankyou'.
                //redirect to thankyou.php
                $target = './views/shop/thankyou.php';
                header('Location: '.$target, true, 307);
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```